# Can run program from Qt but can't run it from konsole

Tags: linux, qt, terminal, opensuse

I have a a problem sounds pretty wierd. I compiled a program in Qt and it ran successfully.

But when I navigated to the release folder in the konsole and ran the program (even with super user), it reported :

```
If 'HelloWorld' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf HelloWorld
```

I checked the permissions, all users can read it.The path is right. I'm out of way.

Please help me!

Note: I use Qt 4.74 on OpenSuse 12.1. Just switched from windows few days ago

I think this ain't relate to the source code, since even a simple HelloWorld program can't run either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program is in the current directory, make sure you run it with a prefix indicating so:

```
./HelloWorld
```

Comment: @Tiana987642 I know, it was for all of us which moved from another system